# Reading unicode one byte at a time

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm trying to create a simple encryption-decryption program (still stuck at I/O, tho):

```
ifstream f("a.in", ios::binary);
ofstream g("a.out");
char x1, x2;
int x,j=0;
f.get(x1);
while(f.get(x2))
{
    if(j==10)
    {
        g<<'\n';
        j=0;
    }
    x=x1+x2;
    x1=x2;
    g<<x<<' ';
    j++;
}
```

Now, the code runs perfectly with ASCII text, however, fails to do so with unicode.

My idea was that, by reading one byte (the 8 bits kind) at a time, I wouldn't have to worry about multi-byte characters and I assumed binary mode would allow me to do that.

Sounds great in theory, not so much in practice, as the program crashes at the very first unicode character.
Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I've searched the web quite extensively, but, apparently it's not something often asked.

tl;dr:
How do I read 8 bits at a time, regardless of their content?

Comment: You _are_ reading `sizeof(char)` which is usually 8 bits at a time. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: That I know, on my machine it is 8 bits, that's why I assumed it would work with unicode, question is, why doesn't it and how do I make it work?

Comment: Please, a [mcve], have no idea what you mean by *"it doesn't work"*. The program you showed shouldn't crash. Its wrong, but shouldn't crash.

Comment: It appears f.read works, if you want to, I could revent the changes and make a couple of printscreens of ASCII and Unicode input.
If I may ask, what do you mean by "It's wrong"?

Comment: Misunderstood what you are doing, apologies

Comment: No problem. Have a great day.

Comment: Encryption makes consistent sense when applied to an array of bytes and the result is almost always an array of bytes. That the input might be text is not relevant to the algorithm. The output should not be interpreted as text.

Comment: Didn't actually think of a mathematical way to encrypt, or to create the key yet. Right now, I got shamefully stuck at the trivial matter of reading the input file. Either way, I have until University starts to think of a way that's supposed to be "somewhat original and somewhat difficult to break". The teacher will mark the math, but the code has to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

f.read(&x1, 1);

get() is intended for text, not binary data.

Comment: Why, thank you, that seemed to be the problem, however, if Passer By could run it, perhaps it's environment-specific.